# Searching Hpricot with Regex

Tags: ruby, regex, hpricot

I'm trying to use Hpricot to get the value within a span with a class name I don't know. I know that it follows the pattern "foo_[several digits]_bar".

Right now, I'm getting the entire containing element as a string and using a regex to parse the string for the tag. That solution works, but it seems really ugly.

```
doc = Hpricot(open("http://scrape.example.com/search?q=#{ticker_symbol}"))
elements = doc.search("//span[@class='pr']").inner_html
string = ""
elements.each do |attr|
  if(attr =~ /foo_\d+_bar/)
    string = attr
  end
end
# get rid of the span tags, just get the value
string.sub!(/<\/span>/, "")
string.sub!(/<span.+>/, "")

return string
```

It seem like there should be a better way to do that. I'd like to do something like:

```
elements = doc.search("//span[@class='" + /foo_\d+_bar/ + "']").inner_html
```

But that doesn't run. Is there a way to search with a regular expression?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do:

```
doc.search("span[@class^='foo'][@class$='bar']")
```

Comment: This looks like what I want. I'll give it a try and see how that goes.

Comment: Worked perfectly! That's exactly what I wanted.

Answer (score 3):

This should do:

```
doc.search("span[@class^='foo'][@class$='bar']")
```

In addition to this we can give some more examples on how some other similar expressions work:

For a document like the following:

We get the output following for each query:

```
doc.search("//meta[@content='abcxy def ghi jklmn']")
=> #<Hpricot::Elements[{emptyelem <meta content="abcxy def ghi jklmn">}]>
```

This is what we would expect.

```
doc.search("//meta[@content='def']")
=> #<Hpricot::Elements[]>
```

As you see = is looking for exact match.

```
doc.search("//meta[@content~='def']")
=> #<Hpricot::Elements[{emptyelem <meta content="abcxy def ghi jklmn">}]>
```

With ~ we can do a substring matching; but not truly what you would expect.

For instance see the following.

```
doc.search("//meta[@content~=' def ']")
=> #<Hpricot::Elements[]>
```

It seems that spaces are treated specially.

With star we can go around this problem. Now we are doing true substring matching.

```
doc.search("//meta[@content*=' def ']")
=> #<Hpricot::Elements[{emptyelem <meta content="abcxy def ghi jklmn">}]>
```

We can also do string begin and string end matching as follows:

```
doc.search("//meta[@content^='def']")
=> #<Hpricot::Elements[]>

doc.search("//meta[@content^='ab']")
=> #<Hpricot::Elements[{emptyelem <meta content="abcxy def ghi jklmn">}]>

doc.search("//meta[@content$='mn']")
=> #<Hpricot::Elements[{emptyelem <meta content="abcxy def ghi jklmn">}]>
```

Note that for these space characters are not a problem.

```
doc.search("//meta[@content$=' jklmn']")
=> #<Hpricot::Elements[{emptyelem <meta content="abcxy def ghi jklmn">}]>
```

Answer (score 0):

One could modify the incoming html before parsing.

```
html = open("http://scrape.example.com/search?q=#{ticker_symbol}").string
html.gsub!(/class="(foo_\d+_bar)"/){ |s| "class=\"foo_bar #{$1}\"" }
doc = Hpricot(html)
```

After that you can identify the elements using the `foo_bar` class.   This is far from elegant or general but could prove to be more efficient.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. That would have worked, except it returns a string. I'd rather get an hpricot Element object back.